# Several questions about paypal pro subscriptions flow

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have integrated standard paypal with one of sites and it works as follows: user selects which subscription to buy, he is redirected to paypal, paypal sends IPN response, I process it and then every X days PayPal sends a new IPN notifying site that user has been successfully charged for new subscription iteration. Now the problem is that user needs to have paypal account to sign up for such subscription.

The customer contacted PayPal and found out that it is possible to avoid having user to use their PayPal account to buy subscription when seller uses paypal pro account. Is it really so? Will I be able to gather user's card info, then send some request to PayPal API and have the subscription created. If yes, what will happen next? PayPal will be sending me IPN requests every X days notifying site that the card has been successfully charged?

Also, what is the general flow? Do I always have to gather card info and send it to paypal api or can I redirect user to paypal in a similar way as standard paypal functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You would need to sign up for PayPal [Website Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/website-payments-pro) and Direct Payment Recurring Payments. You can then use the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API and specify the card details directly in a single API call.

This will create a recurring profile, which is billed every X days / months, depending on what you specified as the billing period in CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Alternatively, you can also sign up for PayPal [Premium Services](https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/premiumservices/) (for the UK) or PayPal [Enhanced Recurring Payments](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview) (for the US). This allows you to accept subscription payments from guest users, using the exact same integration you have at the moment, except a 'guest payment' section will be added to the PayPal checkout screen, so buyers won't be forced to create a PayPal account to sign up for your subscriptions any longer.

(Note: Enhanced Recurring Payments / Premium Services has other benefits as well, such as Installment Plans, but guest subscription payments is definitely the biggest benefit).